# UNION ALL Sql query - how to bind three tables

Tags: sql, db2, union, union-all

I have the following tables:

T1

```
  ID  PRIORITY
  1      1
  2      1
  3      2
  4      4
```

T2

```
ID  SERVICE
1   PSTN
1   ADSL
3   ADSL
```

T3

```
ID   DEVICE
1    BSC1
3    BSC7 
4    BSC7
```

I want as output

```
ID  PRIORITY SERVICE/DEVICE
1      1        PSTN
1      1        ADSL
1      1        BSC1
2      1
3      2        ADSL
3      2        BSC7
```

How to bind those tables using UNION ALL? Also I must put WHERE clause for T1  `WHERE PRIORITY!=4`

Total number in output table for one id should be the summary of T2+T3 (FOR ID=1 2+1=3) but for ID=2 it also **SHOULD** exist in table output with blank second column.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay using just a `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` this should give you what you want

```
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Priority, COALESCE(t2.Service, '') AS [Service/Device]
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.Priority != 4

UNION 

SELECT t1.Id, t1.Priority, COALESCE(t3.Device, '') AS [Service/Device]
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id
WHERE t1.Priority != 4
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d695/18/0)

Comment: thanks for reply...I will try it soon but are you sure I will get duplicate ID values because that is what I want?

Comment: For id 2 will I get null or blank output in Service/device column? Blank is more appropriate but I see in Fiddle that there is null?

Comment: @Dejan I have updated my answer to return blank instead of NULL for you.  Please let me know if this is the output you desired

Answer (score 1):

```
select T1.id , T1.PRIORITY ,T2.SERVICE  as service/Device from  t1 
left outer join T2 on T2.id=T1.id where T1.PRIORITY!=4
union all
select T1.id , T1.PRIORITY ,T3.DEVICE as service/Device from  t1 
left outer join T3 on T3.id=T1.id where PRIORITY!=4
```